# Can't export reducer with Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

This is most likely some typo but I've been trying to fix it for the last hour and came up with nothing.

I have a file called `app/reducers/index.js`:

```
export viewportSize from "./viewportSize";
```

`app/reducers/viewportSize.js` is simply:

```
export default function viewportSize (state = {}) {
  return state;
}
```

And in `app/app.js` I do:

```
import reducers from "./reducers";
```

Babel is giving me back this error

```
ERROR in ./app/reducers/index.js
1:8  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token viewportSize
```

I have other `import` and `export` in the project but this one doesn't want to work.

This is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

**Update**

These are my dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.5.0",
    "eslint": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "1.3.0",
    "webpack": "1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "immutable": "3.7.6",
    "react": "0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "4.4.0",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "3.3.1"
  }
```

**Update**

This is my webpack config file

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: {
    javascript: "./app.js",
    html: "./index.html",
    css: "./style.css",
  },

  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel-loader", "eslint-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: What is your babel version?

Comment: `6.5.2` I've update my question with all the dependencies I'm using

Comment: You're using webpack? Please post webpack config.

Comment: I noticed that if I do `export { viewportSize } from "./viewportSize";` it does not complain

Comment: I've just run this test: https://gist.github.com/srounce/cb12a1af6c3b8dd848da
Everything works as expected. I'm thinkin it's a webpack issue.

Comment: Also, if you use destructuring assignment `export { viewportSize } from "./viewportSize";`, it will not receive the named function `viewportSize` you have passed as the **default export** from `viewportSize.js`, as it will be trying to pull the **named export** `viewportSize`.

Comment: If I do `export { default as viewportSize } from "./viewportSize";` it works.
I'll keep it like that for the moment and try to fix later.

Comment: It seems like you want `import * as reducers from './reducers';` because you're not using a `default`. But there's no point in `reducers/index.js` anyway. You'll need to create a rootReducer that composes the other reducers together.

Comment: @naomik I refactored my code to create a `rootReducer` this way it's more elegant. Still it's strange that my approach didn't work